# Scanning a bit(8) Postgresql column type into a uint8 enum in Go

Tags: go

I'm using a bitwise enum for a Golang project, and I'm storing the bitwise values as a `bit(8)` into Postgresql. The type of enum is a `uint8` as there are only 8 bits for the enum value.

When I persist information to the database and get back values for the `bit(8)` column, it's returning a slice of values. The `Scan(...)` method should convert the `value` to a `uint8` so that the proper `Enum` can be created.

Here is my code to explain it more:

```
type Enum uint8

const (
    A       enum = 1 << 0
    B       enum = 1 << 1
    C       enum = 1 << 2
)
// This method works great. This method is the value the driver uses to
// persist information into the database.
func (u Enum) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%08b", u), nil
}

// This value is responsible for reading info from the database and 
// storing it in a Go type.
func (u *Enum) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    // This does NOT work as I'm getting back `[00110000 00110000 
    //   00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001]` when I 
    //  fmt.Println(value).
    *u = Enum(value.(uint8))
    return nil
}
```

The `value` literally looks like `00000011` in the database. So I'm having trouble for converting the the value received from the driver to into the proper enum value.